# What if thread obtained a lock on object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have gone through an interview and i came accross a question of thread i was bit confused on this. 

If thread has obtained a lock on object, can other threads invoke non-synchronized method on same object?

Comment: Yes, they can..

Comment: If I was asked that question in an interview, I would ask to see example code on the whiteboard. The question, as written above, could be interpreted in more than one way.

Comment: P.S., I would start by pointing out that "synchronized method" really is just syntactic sugar for a method whose body is a synchronized _block_. Then, I would talk only about the behavior of synchronized blocks, which are easier to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class SomeType {
    synchronized SomeOtherType Foobar() {...}
}
```

Is just a shortcut way of writing this:

```
class SomeType {
    SomeOtherType Foobar() {
        synchronized(this) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And This:

```
class SomeType {
    static synchronized SomeOtherType Foobar() {...}
}
```

Is just a shortcut way of writing this:

```
class SomeType {
    static SomeOtherType Foobar() {
        synchronized(SomeType.class) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, every question about "synchronized methods" can be reduced to a question about synchronized blocks.

Most of what you need to know about synchronized blocks can be summed up in two sentences:

1. The JVM will never allow two threads to concurrently execute in blocks that are `synchronized (o)` on the same instance `o`,* and
2. Whatever one thread does to modify shared objects before it exits from a `synchronized (o)` block is guaranteed to become visible to an other thread by the time the other thread enters any block that is synchronized on the same instance `o`.

---

* This is slightly complicated by an `o.wait()` call inside a `synchronized (o)` block. The wait() call releases the lock before it starts waiting, and then re-acquires the lock before it returns.

Technically speaking, any number threads can be "in" `synchronized (o)` blocks for the same instance `o` so long as all but one of those threads is waiting in an `o.wait()` call, but I prefer to say that only one thread can *execute* in the synchronized block and, that "waiting" does not count as "executing."